# How to open new tab with "ctrl+click" instead of redirect current tab, in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, lexicographic

Table contain digital values, each cell has each own `href`.

If I'm apply hrefs like this:

```
nTd.click(function(e){
   $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
   e.stopPropagation();
   location.href = 'http://google.com';
});
```

Each click on cell redirect window, **I can't open new tab by "ctrl + click".**

If I would add in `TD` something like `'<a href="http://google.com"> 123123 </a>'`, then sorting through digital values would breaks, into lexicographical order.

Comment: why don't you say your comment as an answer? @George

Comment: @George - Here you go....http://jsfiddle.net/rntL9ngg/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a check to see whether the CTRL key was down when the event occured:

```
nTd.click(function(e){
   $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
   e.stopPropagation();
    if(e.originalEvent.ctrlKey || e.originalEvent.metaKey){
        window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
    } else {
        location.href = 'http://google.com';   
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rntL9ngg/2/)

You won't see the page change in the fiddle, but you'll see the error it produces in the console.

Comment: Some people also open a link in a new tab by using the middle mouse button, or right clicking and pressing "Open in new tab" in the context menu.

Comment: Sure, I'm one of them, but that's another question.

Comment: Actually (almost) OK, anyway on macOS that should be rather `e.originalEvent.metaKey`

Answer (score 0):

Going off of the initial question my answer would be:
No jquery is needed you can simply change your anchor tag to have the feature `target='_blank'`.
So the full example would be:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"> 123123 </a>
```

**Edit upon more review and another thought**: Alternatively you could add this to your function:

```
window.open('url to open','window name','attribute1,attribute2')
```

So an actual example to jam in there is:

```
nTd.click(function(e){
   $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
   e.stopPropagation();
   window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
});
```

[Anchor Tag Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)
[Javascript open new window reference](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm)

Comment: this was my knee-jerk answer as well, but i think OP wants a jQuery solution because the clicked element seems to be an `td`, not a link. also, it seems the OP wants the new tab behavior *only* when ctrl is pressed while clicking.

Comment: Possible, my Engrish is not so good. I'm talking that I can not format data in cells of table. I can't replace digital `123123` with html code like your.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow ah I see more clearly now.  Looks like George has got it.